# Is there unitary matrix with eigenvalues $1$ , $i$ , $-i$ , $1-i$ , $1+i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unitary-matrices

> Is there unitary matrix with eigenvalues $1$ , $i$ , $-i$ , $1-i$ , $1+i$?

Since modulus of $1+i$ and $1-i$ is not $1$, there exists no such unitary matrix?
However this is a question from a past exam, and that would be way too easy.
I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: It may be too easy, but you are correct.

Comment: "This is an exam question". Really not a great idea to post this online. A class of mine in grad school got in some hot water because one student posted a challenging exam question on here.

Comment: Further to @CameronWilliams's point, do you mean an exam you're literally sitting right now, or a past paper you're revising?

Comment: Its an exam from one of the previous years. I'm from the country you've probably never heard of so no worries

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is correct. Note that suggested eigenvalues all being of modulus $1$ is also a sufficient condition for a unitary matrix to exist.

Comment: Yes I'm aware. Thanks